# Web service timeout during silverlight debug

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, web-services

So I am stepping through my code and now I run the project again to move onto another breakpoint.  However my project doesn't move on instead it crashes saying that I have exceeding the timeout limit for a webservice.

How can I increase the timeout limit for web services so I stop getting these exceptions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify `openTimeout`, `sendTimeout`, `receiveTimeout` and `closeTimeout` attributes of `<binding>` element in your **Web.config** and **ServiceReferences.ClientConfig** files.

For example:

```
<binding name="..." ... openTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" closeTimeout="01:00:00">
    <security mode="Transport" />
</binding>
```

If this answers your question, please "mark it as answer".

Comment: Could  u put the complete web.config section please?

Answer (score 0):

I catch the timeout exception Silverlight side so I can continue to debug after the exception is thrown.